# iPhone iOS large UIView gets clipped to 320x460 when displayed. How to prevent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, bounds

I have a 850x1100 UIView defined in a storyboard it is 4 times the size of a normal window, and I'm using it as a PDF generation template.
 The view is wrapped within a scrollview. Yet when I display the view, its frame gets resized and becomes 320x460, effectively cutting off everything outside the frame.

Does anyone have insight on why my UIView defined in a storyboard as 850x1100 gets its frame reset to 320x460 when displayed on an iPhone?

Comment: did you find a reason why this happened?

Answer (score 3):

This frame recalculation is not a bug.  The frame of a view represents its position and size relative to the screen coordinates.

The iPhone viewing area is 320x480 and any view that has its frame set to a CGRect larger than the viewing area of the device will become "clipped" and have its frame set back to the viewing area (320x460 viewing area due to the status bar).

Try:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(850,1100);
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
pdfView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Comment: I've removed the scrollview entirely. Now my main view outlet is configured with an 850x1100 size in my storyboard. Yet when the main view is finished loading and is dislayed, it's frame gets set to 320x460. It's not clipped, it's literally changing the frame's size.

Comment: Any view that you create that has a frame larger than the viewing area of the device will have its frame reset to the maximum viewing size of the device, in this case 320x460.  Your solution will definitely involve a scrollview as this is the only way (imho) to handle content that is larger than the viewing area.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not the scrollview whose contentsize is too small? It won't automatically resize based on the content - you have to explicitly set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`

Comment: No, my view miraculously gets its frame size changed. To test this I removed all extra views. An 850x1100 view becomes 320x460. I can reset the frame size to the correct size in ViewDidAppear:, but I"m looking for the origin of this peculiar bug.

Comment: There is a lot of "magic" that happens from Storyboard and Interface Builder during the build process.  Some of this magic is resizing your view.